# How do I print line numbers but reset line counter at empty line?

Tags: newlines, line, nl

I have a file.txt containing:

```
this is the first
second line
not last line

fourth but first
second in list
seventh in file
seventh with nl
```

Normally I would just `cat` and pipe `|` it into `nl` like so:

```bsh
$> cat file.txt | nl
1  this is the first
2  second line
3  not last line

4  fourth but first
5  second in list
6  seventh in file
7  seventh with nl
```

But I need the line numbers to reset when it encounters an empty line like so:

```bsh
$> alias_or_function file.txt
1  this is the first
2  second line
3  not last line

1  fourth but first
2  second in list
3  seventh in file
4  seventh with nl
```

How could I do this using a quick function or alias in my `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: A `perl` script can read the file in paragraph-at-a-time mode, onto an array, which you could print out with numbers, beginning at `1` with  each "paragraph". There is a learning curve, but `perl` is worth learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace blank lines with `\:\:` which `nl` understands as the start of a new page body:

```
<your-file sed 's/^[[:space:]]*$/\\:\\:/' | nl
```

So as a function:

```
number-lines-of-paragraphs() {
  sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*$/\\:\\:/' -- "$@" | nl
}
```

(note that `nl` will understand `\:`, `\:\:`, `\:\:\:` as header/body/footer delimiters if they occur in the input as well, which is why you generally can't use `nl` to add line number to arbitrary text).

You could also get the same output format without those caveats with `awk` as:

```
awk 'NF {printf "%6u\t%s\n", FNR, $0; next}; {FNR = 0; print}'
```

Or some of the variants posted by others here.

Above, the numbers are *left padded* to 6 characters and followed by a TAB character like in the default `nl` output format (where `%6u\t%s\n` is the equivalent of `nl`'s default `-s $'\t' -n rn -w 6`), but you can of course adjust that format to your liking.

But now, to make it a function that takes arbitrary file names as arguments, that's where you run into `awk`'s own caveats, namely that it chokes on filenames that contain `=` characters as those are interpreted as awk variable assignment (at least if what's on the left of the first `=` looks like a valid awk variable name). That can be worked around with `gawk` as:

```
number-lines-of-paragraphs() {
  gawk -e '
    NF {printf "%6u\t%s\n", FNR, $0; next}
    {FNR = 0; print}' -E /dev/null "$@"
}
```

Note that if that function is passed several files, the line numbers will be reset at the start of each file. If you'd rather the contents of all files be taken as a single stream to be numbered as a whole like in the `sed | nl` approach, replace `FNR` with `NR` above.

In any case, both `sed` and `gawk` will understand `-` as meaning stdin, not the file called `-` in the current directory (use `./-` to work around it).

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `awk`:

```
$ cat nl.awk
{
   if ( $0 == "" ) {
      count = 0
      print
   } else
      print ++count, $0
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ awk -f nl.awk infile
1 this is the first
2 second line
3 not last line

1 fourth but first
2 second in list
3 seventh in file
4 seventh with nl
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I've never used `print` in Unix before. I also don't know how to use awk but I will definitely be reading up on that because I'm learning now that `awk` has it's own syntax (I'm guessing).

Comment: @ntruter42, that's a `awk` script, not a shell script. So it's not a `print` *command*, but the `print` function in the `awk` language. Having said that, several shells including `ksh` and `zsh` have a `print` builtin. `bash` is an odd one out here, given that it has copied most things from ksh including many of its misdesigns, but not that most basic of builtins, the one to print text. `sed` also has a `print` command, abbreviated as `p`.

Comment: @ntruter42 `awk` has it's own builtin `print` and `printf` functions.  Yes, `awk` has it's own syntax. It is basically `pattern { action }`

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk '{ c=NF?++c:"" } {print c,$0}' file
```

It means:

- If there is any field `NF?` (any (non-space) character), increment `c` with `++c`.
- If there are no fields (no characters), make the line counter empty.
- Print the counter followed by the actual line `print c,$0`

Sadly this short solution converts empty lines to lines that contain an space (or, actually, to the value of OFS). If that is a problem, then use this (similar) solution:

```
awk 'NF{$0=++c" "$0}!NF{c=0}1' file
```

There is no reason to change empty lines to `\:\:` in this solution.